# How to resolve the psr-4 error in Laravel 8?

Tags: laravel, composer-php

In Laravel 8, I use the standard structure:

[image]

The request looks standard:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests\Api\Category;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class StoreCategoryRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required|unique:categories,name'
        ];
    }
}
```

When I run composer dumpaoutoload, I get the following error:

> Class App\Http\Requests\Api\Category\StoreCategoryRequest located in ./app/Http/Requests/Api/Group/StoreCategoryRequest.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.

I tried to change the namespace to `app\Http\Requests\Api\Category` but it doesn't work.

The example above is only one from 10.

I searched for solutions, but nothing helped.

Some idea what  I have to change?

Comment: I assume you meant you ran `composer dump-autoload` (note the hyphen).

Comment: You have shown us the `\Api\Category` file, but the error is about `Api\Group` file. Can we see that please (as well as the file name)?

Comment: The error and the path in the screenshot do not match. You are looking at the wrong file. You need to check on `/app/Http/Requests/Api/Group/`.

Comment: How do I solve?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue, and it turned out I forgot to change the class names when I duplicate the files. Make sure all those 10 files have unique class names. I don't see any other problem on your code, and the namespace should be App...

UPDATE:

The error message says:

```
Class App\Http\Requests\Api\Category\StoreCategoryRequest
located in ./app/Http/Requests/Api/Group/StoreCategoryRequest.php
does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
```

If you look at it, you can see that you have StoreCategoryRequest in "Category" namespace, but in the folder name "Group".

Comment: I checket it all, no error. But I see after `composer dump-autoload` that the reported namespaces are wrong: `./app/Http/Controllers/Api/Group/CategoryController.php` instead of `./app/Http/Controllers/Api/Group/GroupController.php`! I cleaned the cache, uploaded `composer.json` file again, but no difference.

Comment: I can see the difference in the error message. But as shown in the main question, the namespace is ok, but the composer is mixing the namespaces. I copied the files and i changed all namespaces. Does the composer cache some information?

Comment: I don't think it will help, but try ```composer update``` but it will update all packages.  No composer doesn't cache. And I'm sure you will eventually find a mistake you made. I suggest you look at the files again, and again.

Comment: If I run `composer dumpautoload` on my local installation, everything works well...

Comment: I found the error: I work with automatic upload. When i copied the file, it was uploaded immediately. Then I changed the filename, and this was also uploaded. But, because the filenames are different, it doesn't overwrite the first file... Sorry for that